# better way to create objects in Django

Tags: python, django, object, csv

i'm looking for something more "beautiful" to do exactly what i'm doing over here.
Is nicely working right now.

```
f = open(pathdata+'blocoh2.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    dpt, created = Departamento.objects.get_or_create(name = row[3])
    print str(created) + "dprmentp"
    blc, created = Bloco.objects.get_or_create(nm_andar = row[5],name = row[6])
    print str(created) + "bloco"
    tplugar, created = TipoLugar.objects.get_or_create(name = (smart_str(row[2])))
    print str(created) + "tipo_lugar"
    lugar, created = Lugar.objects.get_or_create(name=row[0], utilizacao=row[1], 
                  tipoLugar = tplugar,
                  metragem = 0,
                  coordx = 0,
                  coordy = 0,
                  bloco = blc,
                  departamento = dpt)
    print str(created) + "lugar"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I typically make mine more readable by parsing the legend (or mapping index to name), and referring to columns via a string name instead of a direct index [3]. You're also screwed if the legend order changes ever.

Otherwise, no there's not much you can do about the fact that you have different tables referenced -- you can't directly create these objects from the `Lugar` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and format your code to this Python standard.